# Driving a school bus in the USA

Tags: usa, driving

I am planning on going to the USA with a school trip from Spain and I would like to know if I can drive and rent a Yellow school bus or do I need a special drivers licence?

Any help in this respect would be greatly appreciated. We are planning on doing a part of the Route 66.

Comment: What driving licenses do you have?

Comment: Will it all be within one state? If so, which one?

Comment: This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_bus) says "In 1986, with the signing of the Commercial Motor Vehicle Safety Act, school bus drivers across the United States became required to acquire a [commercial driver's license (CDL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_driver%27s_license). While CDLs were issued by individual states, the federal CDL requirement ensured that drivers of all large vehicles (such as school buses) had a consistent training level." It seems to imply that the license is required because of the large vehicle, not its specific use.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's true if you recognize that "size" can mean either weight or passenger capacity.  The CDL requirement can be triggered (for a single vehicle; it's more complicated if there's towing involved) by the weight of the vehicle (over 26000 lbs maximum gross, which is 11793 kg) or by the number of passengers for which the vehicle is designed (16 or more, including the driver).

Comment: How many people do you intend to drive in the bus?

Comment: You might want to reconsider driving and the Yellow Bus. They are notoriously uncomfortable with little for safety. A coach bus with a professional driver is much more safe & comfortable, even if it's more expensive. I rode a yellow bus as a kid and took high school trips in coach buses, so I have some experience here. Since this doesn't directly answer the question, I'm putting it as a comment.

Comment: @computercarguy While you can't doubt uncomfortable, modern school buses are safer than normal buses, especially since they have strict crashworthiness standards don't apply to ordinary buses. The law has provisions requiring the purchase of school buses. [See NHTSA](https://www.nhtsa.gov/road-safety/school-bus-safety). They are much safer than 12 and 15 passenger vans, which are notorious for rolling over.

Comment: @user71659, they might have safety regs, but that doesn't mean they are safe. Kids get killed in them too frequently in accidents. A coach bus is going to have way higher safety standards, regardless. And a professional coach driver is much less likely to have an accident than a freshly trained foreign driver. (No disrespect to foreign drivers intended.)

Comment: @computercarguy The first line of the NHTSA page: "four to six school-age children die each year on school transportation vehicles". That is absolutely negligible in light of the ~40,000 traffic deaths per year. Use real data, not feelings. And that's the point, coach buses _do not_ have stricter standards, they are _far less strict_. You're just spreading a myth.

Comment: @user71659, the stats the NHTSA states are more than a little lop sided, mostly due to school buses being generally run at lower than highway speeds. https://www.louisianamotorcoach.com/too-cool-for-school-5-safety-features-charter-buses-have-that-school-buses-dont/ and https://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/safety/passenger-safety/legal-notice-motorcoach-operations show that there's a lot of regulations and safety features for coaches that don't necessarily apply to buses.

Comment: @Acccumulation The _Which state?_ comment appears on every question about the USA. Europeans think the USA is a single country, when in fact, it's more like a loose federation of 50 small countries, all with their own ideas.

Comment: One more vote for "Hire a coach bus" - much more comfortable.  Even here in Florida (hot and humid) I've never seen a school bus with air conditioning... other than the "cabriolet" versions the watermelon pickers make with a cutting torch...   If you must have that authentic "stuck to naugahyde seat covers sweating to death in a no noise insulation loud metal tube" experience, depending on time of year some school districts may actually rent you a bus and qualified driver ...

Answer (score 10):

Federal law mandates that a commercial driver's license or CDL, issued by a state (or territory or the District of Columbia) is [required to operate](https://cms.fmcsa.dot.gov/registration/commercial-drivers-license/drivers)

> Class A: Any combination of vehicles which has a gross combination weight rating or gross combination weight of 11,794 kilograms or more (26,001 pounds or more) whichever is greater, inclusive of a towed unit(s) with a gross vehicle weight rating or gross vehicle weight of more than 4,536 kilograms (10,000 pounds) whichever is greater.
>
> Class B: Any single vehicle which has a gross vehicle weight rating or gross vehicle weight of 11,794 or more kilograms (26,001 pounds or more), or any such vehicle towing a vehicle with a gross vehicle weight rating or gross vehicle weight that does not exceed  4,536 kilograms (10,000 pounds).
>
> Class C: Any single vehicle, or combination of vehicles, that does not meet the definition of Class A or Class B, but is either **designed to transport 16 or more passengers, including the driver**, or is transporting material that has been designated as hazardous under 49 U.S.C. 5103 and is required to be placarded under subpart F of 49 CFR Part 172 or is transporting any quantity of a material listed as a select agent or toxin in 42 CFR Part 73.

The specific classification of license you need is dependent on the state, but you are required to have a CDL with sufficient endorsements if the school bus is designed to seat 16 or more passengers, even if there are a fewer than 16 of you.

If your group is indeed that large, you can rent large vans or mini-buses configured to seat up to 15 (e.g. Ford Transit, Mercedes-Benz Sprinter). Just search for "15-passenger buses" or shuttles, designed specifically to fall under the limit. If you have your heart set on the iconic yellow school bus, a quick web search did turn up a few companies that have configured school buses to seat 14 or 15, though these seem to be aimed at in-town excursions (e.g. youth groups, bachelor parties), and I cannot say whether any would be willing to rent you one for a cross-country trip.

Comment: Note that states have [specific CDL exemptions for RVs](http://changingears.com/rv-sec-state-rv-license.shtml). As the page explains, a CDL is only necessary for a commercial motor vehicle. The OP presumably is not using the school bus to transport pupils or provide a service for hire, and therefore may fall under these exemptions.

Comment: I had forgotten about RVs, though I note that the internal configuration of the RV is going to determine how many passengers it can reasonably carry. I agree in that fundamentally, it comes down to how the federal requirement is expressed and enforced in state law; the AAA [Types of Driver’s Licenses](https://drivinglaws.aaa.com/tag/types-of-drivers-licenses/) page is presumably reliable.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt very highly that you will be able to find anyone who will rent or lease a school bus to you unless the driver has a driver's license issued under [federal commercial driver's license (CDL) regulations with an S endorsement](https://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/registration/commercial-drivers-license/drivers).

According to the [Federal Motor Carrier Safety Administration](https://www.fmcsa.dot.gov/international-programs/commercial-and-non-commercial-driver-license-requirements), there is reciprocity with Canada and Mexico, but if you have a foreign license that allows you to drive buses from another jurisdiction, you might be able to get a "temporary waiver" of the federal CDL requirement.  These are said to be "rare," however.

Comment: IANAL but note that "school bus" refers to vehicles used for transporting children to and from school. There are special requirements for those drivers, such as a sex offender check, and training on how to stop on the street. These are obviously not relevant for a vehicle in private use. While the OP is driving a vehicle originally designed to transport pupils, they aren't transporting students, so it isn't a "school bus" as defined by many regulations.

Comment: @user71659 the [definition of school bus](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/390.5) applies to the vehicle, and the requirement to have an [endorsement](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/383.5) also depends on the type of vehicle, not the use to which it is put.  The definition applies to a vehicle "which is designed or used to carry more than 10 passengers in addition to the driver, and which the Secretary determines is likely to be significantly used for the purpose of...."  It does not stop being a school bus when it is driven for other purposes.

Comment: Incorrect. You missed the part with "and which... is determined to be significantly used". In fact, my state takes a very narrow view of that definition: buses used on field trips (i.e. don't take kids to their homes) are _not_ yellow or marked as school buses, they're white and "[activity buses](https://thomasbuiltbuses.com/more-buses/activity-buses/)". The other thing you missed is that a CDL is needed for a commercial motor vehicle. The definition of commercial motor vehicle requires use "in interstate commerce". Hence, RVs and things rental trucks (U-Haul) are regulated separately.

Comment: I think it's more important to understand that the OP was using the term "school bus" as a more generic term to describe the look/style of the vehicle, rather than it's purpose. @user71659

Comment: @user71659 commercial vehicles that are not driven across state lines do not fall under federal CDL regulations, but not all states issue non-CDL licenses to drive such vehicles. Mine used to, but stopped. But that has nothing to do with rental trucks. These can be driven with a non CDL only because -- and only if -- their GVWR is 26,000 lbs or less.  And a rented *bus* is certainly a commercial motor vehicle.  Even if it isn't a school bus requiring an S endorsement, it will require a P endorsement.

Comment: @user71659: There is a separate definition for "school bus operation" which covers the more specific meaning you are describing. Unless you can get the Secretary of Transportation to *individually* sign off on your particular vehicle as "not a school bus," it's still a school bus under the Federal regulation, regardless of what individual states think of the issue.

Comment: See [this thread](http://www.skoolie.net/forums/f18/nys-r-endorsement-doesnt-cover-air-brakes-3033.html). It is exactly on the topic of private enthusiasts owning school buses, and they say a Class D (ordinary car) with R endorsement, which is what you do for large RVs. They also point out that in NY it has to be repainted from yellow.

Answer (score 3):

Each state in the US has its own regulations regarding licensing for drivers.

In most states (if not all), you will need a special category of license to operate a bus with passengers. [Here](http://www.mva.maryland.gov/drivers/apply/license-class-codes.htm) are the classes of driver's licenses in Maryland, for example. You would need CDL Endorsement "S" in Maryland (not on Rt. 66, obviously, but it's an example).

If you are going to be driving in multiple states, you may need licensing and registration with the federal government as well (e.g., the US Department of Transportation), but I'm not sure about that.

Renting a bus with the intention of driving passengers, will have its own set of complications, since the liability insurance will be quite different than just driving yourself and a few other passengers. Be aware that the rules of the road are different (school buses must stop at all railroad crossings even if the lights are not flashing, for example).

Finally, unless you are actually driving a bus for a school (and are an employee of a school district or a contractor for one), you will probably not be permitted to drive a vehicle with "SCHOOL BUS" markings.

Answer (score 2):

Since you hold a european driving license, I suggest you acquire an [International Driving Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit). And since you're in Spain, do check the page about ["Permiso Internacional" in the Dirección General de Trafico website](https://sede.dgt.gob.es/es/tramites-y-multas/permiso-de-conduccion/permiso-internacional/). It'll take one visit to your nearest DGT office and 10.30€ (as of 2018).

It's not needed in all cases, but [some states require it](https://www.usa.gov/visitors-driving):

> People who drive in the U.S. must have a valid driver's license. Some
>   states require an International Driving Permit (IDP) from foreign
>   nationals, in addition to a valid license from your own country.
>   [Contact the motor vehicle department of each
>   state](https://www.usa.gov/motor-vehicle-services) you will drive in
>   for its requirements.

Furthermore, car/bus rental companies commonly require you to hold an IDP. These might in fact be able to tell you if you need an IDP to rent a bus.

Even though it might not be needed, it doesn't hurt to do so - it's just a translation of the fields in your Spanish license card, which can be helpful if you need to show your license to a person who doesn't speak any Spanish at all. The [spanish ministry of external affairs recommends visitors to have one as well](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Portal/es/ServiciosAlCiudadano/SiViajasAlExtranjero/Paginas/DetalleRecomendacion.aspx?IdP=63):

> España no tiene convenio con ningún estado de los EE.UU. sobre validez
>   del permiso de conducir español en ese país. Por tanto, los turistas o
>   los españoles en viaje de negocios en EE.UU. deberán obtener en
>   España, y previamente a su llegada a EE.UU., el permiso internacional
>   de conducción, que tiene validez de un año y es reconocido por EE.UU.
>   En caso contrario, podrían ser sancionados por carecer de permiso de
>   conducir reconocido por las autoridades de tráfico locales.

As other answers point out, laws vary by state. It's up to each state to recognize a class D (bus) european license + IDP as a document enabling you to drive buses - or not. I suggest you [find the DMV office for the specific state(s) you're visiting](https://www.usa.gov/motor-vehicle-services) and ask there.